# VST Plugins to filter mic input for Skype or Google Hangouts

Tags: microphone, vst, plug-ins

I'm a user of Reaper and OBS, but nevertheless it seems I cannot find a good solution for my problem:

We have a conference room with 3 microphones that go into an AKG mixer & audio interface. In Windows, I see one input-device which is the mixdown of the microphones. Unfortunately, the signal from the microphones has an impressive noise floor and it could also use some eq adjustments. All this can easily be done with a noise-gate and some simple filters.

**Question:** Is there an easy program that can sit between the pure mic input and act as a man in the middle to adjust the signal that goes to Hangouts, Skype, or Discord?

When I understood this correctly, then I need e.g. a VST host which creates a virtual device as its output that I can then select as "microphone" in the application. I've seen that I can do this with DAW applications but one requirement is that it will be easy to fire up once all filters are set up. This is necessary because it basically needs to be started by anyone who wants to make a conference call.

I can provide further information if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of application you probably want a mixing desk that can handle automixing - something like a Yamaha QL-1 which has an in-built Dugan Automixer. This will significantly help with the noise-floor. Also you need to look and see how the mics are being used. IF the microphones are a long way from the subjects, then you will definitely get noise problems. This sounds partly like an installation and usage issue coupled with a technical issue. I would try and get the signal as clean as possible coming out of the desk. Plugins on the computer will only add latency and that will cause other problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware that the noise is a result of the circumstances of having room microphones and not the best equipment. I agree that investing in better equipment should be the goal, but if this is not possible then digital filters would be a cheap improvement. In practice, many streamers on twitch do exactly the same (although they tend to have good mics) and latency wouldn't be an issue considering that the lag of e.g. Skype would be much higher. So I still wonder about a program that does the job. (+1)

Comment: The latency isn't an issue of the transmission channel, its more an issue of retaining sync with the picture. If you're on Mac, take a look at MenuBus. Not sure about windows solutions but I'm sure they are out there.

Comment: Yes, I know. Usually, with several participants, the image quality is mediocre at best and if I could improve the quality at the cost of some de-sync, I guess that would be OK. After all, talking is much more important here than seeing the person.